# text cleaning in python

Tags: python-3.x, replace, nlp

If I need to clean text in R, I could chain the multiple operations by:

```r
ssids$text%>% 
  str_replace_all( "[^\x01-\x7E]", "") %>% #remove hex encoding
  replace_non_ascii %>%
  str_replace_all("\\b([a-z]+)\\b(?:\\s+\\1\\b)+","\\1") %>% #remove duplicates word appearing together 
  str_replace_all('[:digit:]', '')%>% #remove digits
  str_replace_all( "[^[:alnum:]///' ]", "") %>% #remove special characters 
  str_replace_all( "[:punct:]", "") %>% #remove punctuation
  scrubber() %>% # clean and replace other textual anomalies
  str_to_lower() # convert text to lower case
```

The above code cleans the `text` column within the `ssids` dataframe. It performs each operation and sends the results down to the next operation....

How do I do this in a similar manner in python?

Answer (score 0):

You can use re.sub and use regex to replace all those characters, here are their [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub), and here is a usage example from there:

```
>>> def dashrepl(matchobj):
...     if matchobj.group(0) == '-': return ' '
...     else: return '-'
>>> re.sub('-{1,2}', dashrepl, 'pro----gram-files')
'pro--gram files'
>>> re.sub(r'\sAND\s', ' & ', 'Baked Beans And Spam', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
'Baked Beans & Spam'
```

You can do the same idea, just for your hex encoding symbols.

To make it all lowercase in Python, just do your str.lower()